# No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am new to spring world. I have been trying to write a basic application using spring data, JPA using Hibernate and MYSql Database.
I am seeing the error:

> No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier
>   'transactionManager'

Here is my spring-config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.levadata.models" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.levadata" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/levadata_beta" />
     <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    </bean>

      <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jcgPersistence" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
  </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
   </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

Here is my Employee.java(myPOJO):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "employee_id")
private long employeeId;

@Column(name = "employee_name")
private String employeeName;

public Employee() {
}

public Employee(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}

public long getEmployeeId() {
    return this.employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public String getEmployeeName() {
    return this.employeeName;
}

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
    this.employeeName = employeeName;
}
}
```

Here is my repository:

> ```
> public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>
> {
>   Employee save(Employee employee);
>
>   //@Query("select distinct employee_name from employee")
>   //public Slice<String> findAllDistinctNames(Pageable pageable);
>   public Slice<String> findAllByEmployeeName(Pageable pageable);
> }
> ```

Finally My POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.levadata</groupId>
<artifactId>exampleLytica</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>exampleLytica</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-data.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data.version>

    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.levadata.Application</start-class>

</properties> 

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
 <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- optional -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try
            {
                    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration.xml");
                    System.out.println("Context : " + context);
                    //Fetch the DAO from Spring Bean Factory
                    EmployeeRepository repository = (EmployeeRepository)context.getBean("employeeRepository");
                    Employee employee = new Employee("Employee123");
                    //employee.setEmployeeId("1");

                    //Save an employee Object using the configured Data source
                    repository.save(employee);
                    System.out.println("Employee Saved with EmployeeId "+employee.getEmployeeId());

                    //find an object using Primary Key
                    Employee emp = repository.findOne(employee.getEmployeeId());
                    System.out.println(emp);

                    //Close the ApplicationContext
                    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();

            }
            catch (BeansException e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

When I run the code, I am getting below stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:56)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineQualifiedTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:377)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:361)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.save(Unknown Source)
at com.levadata.SpringDataDemo.main(SpringDataDemo.java:26)
```

Any idea, which piece I am missing here.

Comment: In your EmployeeRepository Implementation class, do you have @Transactional annotation?

Comment: EmployeeRepository doesn't have an implementation. Spring implements it by itself.

Answer (score 9):

May be Spring wants transaction manager and default name is transactionManager. So try to rename txManager to transactionManager. Or specify current manager name where it needs.

Comment: making it to 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">

from

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">

worked for me.

Comment: What to do if the same error came for spring boot? Also I have give @Transactional  annotation

Comment: Try to look at initialization log. Is the datasource created? Maybe you are missing something like spring-boot-starter-jpa or JPA provider (Hibernate).